# Using Rascal MAP

Tags: dictionary, rascal

I am trying to create an empty map, that will be then populated within a for loop. Not sure how to proceed in Rascal. For testing purpose, I tried:

```
rascal>map[int, list[int]] x;
ok
```

Though, when I try to populate "x" using:

```
rascal>x += (1, [1,2,3])
>>>>>>>;
>>>>>>>;
        ^ Parse error here
```

I got a parse error.

Comment: Maps key values are separated by : as in (1:2,2:3)

Answer (score 3):

To start, it would be best to assign it an initial value. You don't have to do this at the console, but this is required if you declare the variable inside a script. Also, if you are going to use `+=`, it has to already have an assigned value.

```
rascal>map[int,list[int]] x = ( );
map[int, list[int]]: ()
```

Then, when you are adding items into the map, the key and the value are separated by a `:`, not by a `,`, so you want something like this instead:

```
rascal>x += ( 1 : [1,2,3]);
map[int, list[int]]: (1:[1,2,3])

rascal>x[1];
list[int]: [1,2,3]
```

An easier way to do this is to use similar notation to the lookup shown just above:

```
rascal>x[1] = [1,2,3];
map[int, list[int]]: (1:[1,2,3])
```

Generally, if you are just setting the value for one key, or are assigning keys inside a loop, `x[key] = value` is better, `+=` is better if you are adding two existing maps together and saving the result into one of them.

Answer (score 2):

I also like this solution sometimes, where you instead of joining maps just update the value of a certain key:

```
m = ();
for (...whatever...) {
   m[key]?[] += [1,2,3];
}
```

In this code, when the key is *not* yet present in the map, then it starts with the `[]` empty list and then concatenates `[1,2,3]` to it, or if the key *is* present already, let's say it's already at [1,2,3], then this will create `[1,2,3,1,2,3]` at the specific key in the map.

Comment: This is a clean notation for an operation that has to be done many times in Racal. Great work!

Comment: We appreciate the compliment. 